# Cannot authenticate to sharepoint farm using HTTP in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

plot:

There's on-prem developer farm (w2012r2, sql2012, vs2013pro). All stuff configured: services, dns, app urls, no host header, no hostnamed sites, even disabled loopback.
Main thing is there's no https configured.

And there's my local machine (w8.1pro, vs2015ce). Also my account is SPShellAdmin.

So problem is when i'm creating sharepoint hosted app project, visual studio prompts for credentials again ang again. Eventually it's goes offline. Thus no debug, no deploy and so on.

However, connecting to prod farm via https works just fine(no surprise here).

BUT. It connects from prod server visual studio to dev farm with no issues.

So. May be i'm missing some windows features or so? Is there a way to work with just http from local machine?

Thank you!